# Create datatable columns from a variable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I hope you are fine.

My question today is about Datatables. I've working with them around a month more or less and it's a fantastic plugin.

Today, I'm trying to improve my code, so I want to create the Datatables columns from a variable which has all the 'th' tags that table has.

The table is coming from a freemarker that I have, and I'm getting it right, but I don't figure out how to put the columns in the datatables in a proper way.

Here's my code:

```
columns = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
```

With that I get all the columns from the Freemarker, and the console output it's this:

[image]

But when I try to put all the th in the "columns" section, I get a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

So, the thing here is:

**How can I put the "columns": columns in a proper way to display them?**

Thank you so much for your help or anything you can provide.

Edit:

Here you have my full code for the Datatable:

```
    function ConsoleDataTable(dataTableName, columns) 
{
    var me = this;
    columns = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
    console.log(columns)


    me.dataTableName =  dataTableName;
    me.datTableObject = $("#dt_" + this.dataTableName ).DataTable({
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'hidden-xs col-sm-6'lC>r>"+
                    "Zt"+
                    "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'hidden-xs col-sm-6'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>",
            //"autoWidth" : true,
            "fnInitComplete": function() {
               this.removeClass("hidden");
               $("#dt_" + dataTableName).wrap( "<div class='tableWrap'></div>" );
            },
          "columns": columns

    });
```

And this is my Freemarker where I create the basic structure:

```
  <table id="${table_id?has_content?then(table_id, 'dt_basic')}" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover datatable hidden" width="100%" 

        <#if extraData?has_content>
            <#list extraData?keys as key> 
                data-${key}="${extraData[key]}"
            </#list>        
        </#if>      
>
    <thead class="invert">              
        <tr class="invert">
            <#list rows.getCols() as col>
                <th class="text-center">
                    <#if selectName??>
                        ${col.getColumnName()}
                    <#else>
                        ${col.getColumnLabel()!col.getColumnName()}
                    </#if>
                </th>
            </#list>
        </tr>

        <#if rows.hasHeaders()>
        <tr class="invert">
            <#list rows.getHeaders() as header>
            <td  class="text-center" colspan='${header.getColspan()}'>${header.getHeader()}</td>
            </#list>
        </tr>
        </#if>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <#list rows.getRows() as row>
            <tr>
                <#list rows.getCols() as col>
                    <#if col.isRightAligned()>
                    </#if>
                    <td style='${col.getColumnStyle()}'>
                        <#if col.getColumnHref()??>
                            <a href='${col.getColumnHref()}'>
                        </#if>
                        ${row[col.getColumnName()]}
                        <#if col.getColumnHref()??>
                            </a>
                        </#if>
                    </td>
                </#list>
            </tr>
        </#list>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I just added all I can, thx for your help sir.

Comment: @DavidOlivia - Thanks a lot. OK. I fail to see **why** you want to define `columns` dynamically, you do not need a `columns` property at all when you are instantiating a dom `<table>` as you doing here. It is only needed when you are using some kind of data.  You are literally constructing both `<thead>` and the entire `<tbody>` structure yourself, what should the purpose of columns be here...? Sry if I totally misunderstand ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @davidkonrad. The main idea here (and i would explain in the best way i can).

We have a java file that send us a jSon with data. We process this data throught DataTable and the main 'table' example we use is the Freemarker what I linked to you. 

But, if we want to set differents widths for each column, for every single table (we have around 150 tables) we want to do it in dynamically. 

I'm sorry if this is not clear, it's a little bit complicated for me to explain all this (i'm just a junior developer :( )